# Error when trying to re-use the "this" property in an object, it loses scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following object:

```
var data = {
    el : $('.element'),
    value1 : this.el.data('value1')
}
```

Why does `this` lose scope?  And throw an error?

I could just do the following, but it's not efficient since I am basically selecting the div twice:

```
var data = {
    el : $('.element'),
    value1 : $('.element').data('value1')
}
```

This works for functions:

```
    var data = {
        el : $('.element'),
       test : function () {

       console.log(this.el) // works
    }

}
```

Comment: It isn't losing scope at all, it simply isn't what you think it is. You haven't changed the scope yet, the scope where you are using `this` is the same as it was on the line before `var data = {`

Comment: Just trying to clarify your scope issue.

When you are defining "data" the "this" scope is still the global scope.. data isn't defined yet. The javascript engine attempts to evaluate the this.el.data('value1') before data has been fully evaluated so this just simply can't be a reference to data yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var $element = $('.element');
var data = {
    el : $element,
    value1 : $element.data('value1')
}
```

`this` doesn't belong to jQuery, when you select an element with jQuery it does not change the value of `this` in the scope that you are in.  `this` is basically the object that contains the **function** you are in.  Sometimes there are jQuery methods that will turn `this` into a DOM element, you need to read the documentation for whatever method you are using. We cannot determine what `this` is from this snippet of code because it doesn't contain a function.

Answer (score 1):

another option, I suppose would be this:

`var data = {
   e : $('.element'),
   value1: function(){return this.e.data();}
}`

I'm not really happy with that solution but it would fully encapsulate everything inside data

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have tried just now:

What do you think?

```
var data = {
   el : $('.element'),
   initialize: function() {

     this.mydata = this.el.data('mydata');
   }
}
```

Comment: This is good because it allows you to re-initialize it as needed, however, i think i would prefer just making `mydata` a function that returns the data. To each his own.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

```
var data = {
    el : $('.element'),
    value1 : function () {
       return this.el.data('value1')    
    }
}
console.log(data.value1());//foobar 
console.log(data.value1.call({}));//error

var data = {
    el : $('.element'),
    value1 : function () {
       return data.el.data('value1')    
    }
}
console.log(data.value1());//foobar 
console.log(data.value1.call({}));//foobar
```

in second method the value will always refer to data even if u call the function in any scope

Comment: Is this efficient, I'm not sure how this works - referring an object to itself?

Comment: if you want to call the data.value in any function scope and you want to get `this` as data you can use this..

Comment: this doesn't work, `data` is still undefined at that point. http://jsfiddle.net/Nhfdn/

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
el = $('.element');
var data = {
    el : el,
    value1 : el.data('value1')
}
```

anyway, that looks weird, maybe some more context can help make it look better (why would you pass a jQuery object and it's value on an object when you can get the value from the jQuery object?)

Comment: the data object will have lots of properties and methods - and if I do it like this, el will be declared globally, which is not really good in complex applications - like using backbone js